# boolean metadata with value other than true or false when launching nemo

Tags: nemo

When I launch nemo I get this error

```
** (nemo:55622): ERROR **: 19:38:37.567: boolean metadata with value other than true or false
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

How do I fix this?

System:

- Linux mint 20 64-bit
- MATE desktop

Comment: I made an issue on github and the creators of nemo told me to use this command (and it worked) gio set ~ metadata::nemo-icon-view-auto-layout true

Answer (score 1):

I found out I had old volumes and disks in metadata, so I just removed them and it worked.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*
```